# Using IIS to host a express node.js backend

Tags: express, reverse-proxy, iis-10, http-status-code-500

I created a website using express, I hosted it once with IIS, and it worked except for API calls, they were being rewritten.  I tried to fix it but ended up breaking everything.  I tried to refollow my steps, and follow the sources I found the first time to set it up, but nothing works!  I have no clue what I need to do or what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The express application works perfectly on localhost, so it shouldn't be anything with that.

I'm going to bring you through the steps I think I should be taking:

In IIS this is under the server name part

I enabled proxy here 
[image: I enabled proxy here]

The rest of the information just in case I changed something by accident. 
[image: The rest of the information]

I've found contradicting paths to take from here.  One says to use a Reverse Proxy, the other says to just use a URL rewrite.  I've tried both and neither is working.

This is the under "Sites" 
[image: This is the under "Sites"]

I saw the option to do it under the server or the site specifically, I'm not sure which one I should be using, but I tried both.

From the tutorials, it should work, but I get a 500- Internal server error

Some other information that could be useful:

my Site bindings 
[image: my Site bindings]

I do not have it set up for HTTPS

My physical path: (I'm very unsure if this is the correct way to do it, but it worked before)

This directory has the index.js file for the server 
[image: This directory has the index.js file for the server]

My best guess at troubleshooting is that something is wrong with the rewrite because it doesn't seem to get any traffic. I could be wrong, I'm new to all of this and jumping in very blindly. If I forgot to include anything important let me know and I will include it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using failed request tracing and get the detail where you failed. Generally this error occurred when did not find requested content.

[Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)

You should be able to see the rewritten rule in the trace, try accessing the URL directly to see if you get the 500. Also check the IIS logs on both the IIS and ARR server to see on which one the 500 is happening.

Follow the below article to create reverse proxy:

[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)